# SSIS - Saving to Office 2007 Format

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to save an excel spreadhseet from SQL Server Integration Services 2005.

Unfortunatly I only seem to be able to save in 2003 format but I want to be able to save in 2007 format. Is there wa way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible using the OLEDB connection manager. (Not the Excel connection.)

Take a look at [this example](http://bensullins.com/using-excel-2007-files-as-a-source-in-ssis-2005/). It is for importing, but it should be suitable for exporting as well. 
Remember to use the XML format as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280527.aspx). And in more detail [here](http://dougbert.com/blogs/dougbert/archive/2009/02/13/exporting-data-from-ssis-to-excel-2007-gotchas.aspx).

Comment: I’ve managed to write to an excel 2007 workbook as described in the section “Connecting to a Workbook in Excel 2007 Format “ at this url  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280527.aspx

The trick is to use an OLE DB connection for the workbook rather than an excel connection (of course!). According to this link http://dougbert.com/blogs/dougbert/archive/2008/06/16/excel-in-integration-services-part-1-of-3-connections-and-components.aspx will need to wait for 2008 before they let you choose the 2007 workbook as an option 